# QT or QML: Catching app close event in mobile app

Tags: qt, mobile, qml, forceclose

I have an app which uses a QML `MediaPlayer` to play music.
Via:

```
   Connections {
      target: Qt.application
      onStateChanged: {
         // ...
      }
   }
```

I am able to note when the app goes to the background, or when it comes to the foreground again.

However, I don't get any event when the user *closes* the app. The problem is, when playing music, and the app is closed, the music playback continues. As a result, I need a way to catch the close event and stop music playback.

I am on Ubuntu Touch, and therefore I have no `Window` instance where I could catch the `closing` event. In the `QGuiApplication` / `Qt.application` there seems to be no viable signal either; I have tried catching `lastWindowClosed`, but it never gets triggered.

Long story short:
How can I get notified when the app is about to close so I can stop music playback?

My main.cpp is pretty much the default and looks like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication* app = new QGuiApplication(argc, (char**)argv);

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView();
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/Main.qml"));
    view->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view->show();

    return app->exec();
}
```

Comment: Could you just listen for `Component.onDestruction` of your main application window?

Comment: Didn't work. While there was no error, adding code there to stop music playback has no effect, and playback continues after app closing.

Comment: Try to catch onClosing event from your mainwindow in main.qml.
```onClosing: {
// do ur action here
}
```

Comment: @RamkumarR as stated above, I don't have a `Window` instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, after googling even more. Some guy at the QT forum revealed:

```
   Connections {
      target: Qt.application

      onAboutToQuit: {
         audioPlayer.stop()
      }
```

This works